# Сортировка объектов по алфавиту

Tags: java, ооп, сортировка, объекты

Как отсортировать объекты по инициалам?
Т.е когда я буду заполнять массив объектов, хочу чтобы они выводились не в порядке заполнения, а по алфавитному порядку инициалов)
Если заполню вот так

```
Workers {initials = 'Я', position = 'блабла', year = 2017}
Workers {initials = 'А', position = 'блабла', year = 2017}
```

А должно выводить

```
Workers {initials = 'А', position = 'блабла', year = 2017}
Workers {initials = 'Я', position = 'блабла', year = 2017}
```

Заранее спасибо)

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
Worker[] workers = new Worker[2];
String initials, position;
int year = 0;

System.out.print("Заполните информацию про рабочих." +
            "\n" + "Введите : ФИО , должность , " +
            "год поступления на работу v" + "\n" + "Вводите: ");
//Ввод данных

for (int i = 0; i < workers.length; i++) {
    workers[i] = new Worker(initials = reader.readLine(), position = reader.readLine(), year = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
}

//Вывод массива

for (Worker worker : workers) {
    System.out.println(worker.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть два варианта - либо сделать класс `Worker` сравнимым по инициалам

```
public class Worker implements Comparable<Worker> {
    ...

    public int compareTo(Worker worker) {
        return getInitials().compareTo(worker.getInitials());
    }
}
```

либо использовать для сортировки [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

```
Comparator<Worker> workerInitialsComparator
  = Comparator.comparing(Worker::getInitials);

Arrays.sort(workers, workerInitialsComparator);
```

Comment: Спасибо , я кстати и то и то пробовал , но не разобрался что компаратор и компарейбл должен возвращать))
Пойду попробую , еще раз благодарю

Comment: А не подскажешь , если бы вместо простого массива был бы ArrayList например , как там вытягивать инициалы и сравнивать ?

Comment: Для первого решения вообще ничего не меняется. Во втором случае вместо `Arrays.sort()` использовать `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: Спасибо , буду пробовать

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)